# Find the largest table in a page

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Could someone tell me how I can find the largest table in a web page (i.e. the one with the most rows) using Nokogiri? Can this be done using Lambda functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
biggest_table = doc.xpath('//table').max_by do |table|
  table.xpath('.//tr').length
end
```

Or, in case there's a tie, perhaps you want a list of all tables with the most rows:

```
# Hash mapping number of rows to array of table nodes
tables = doc.xpath('//table').group_by{ |t| t.xpath('.//tr').length }

# Array of all (possibly only 1) tables with the most rows
biggest_n = tables[table.keys.max]
```

Comment: Thanks Phrogz. I got this now as a one-liner `biggest_table = doc.xpath('//table').max_by {|table| table.xpath('.//tr').length}`

Comment: Here's the one for 10k... Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are looking for, but you can do this easily on the browser using jQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

```
tables = @doc.xpath('//table')
tr_count = tables.map{|n| n.xpath('tr|*/tr').length}
biggest_table = tables[tr_count.index(tr_count.max)]
```